# Http post request does not work

Tags: angular

I am trying to send a http post request to back-end rest api. Here is the code of http service:

```
@Injectable()
export class requestService{

    constructor(private _http:Http){}

    postRequest(request:any){
        console.log("Here is post")
        const body=JSON.stringify(request);
        let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
        let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

        this._http.post('http://localhost:8080/requests',body,options).map(res=> console.log(res.headers));

    }

}
```

I am sure that my back end is working fine. I successfully send a post request by postman. But when, i send the request using my service, nothing happens. There is no error. Also, the object is not recorded to the back-end too.

So, what is the problem?

Comment: try this ----`this._http.post('http://localhost:8080/requests',body,options).map(res=> console.log(res.data));`

Comment: I don’t know angular, but are you sure you are even catching errors? Do you have an error callback somewhere?

Comment: @micronyks it doesn't work.

Comment: do you get headers in console ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Observables` are lazy. Without subscribing, they won't to anything.

Either use `subscribe()` instead of `map()`

```
@Injectable()
export class requestService{

    constructor(private _http:Http){}

    postRequest(request:any){
        console.log("Here is post")
        const body=JSON.stringify(request);
        let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
        let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

        this._http.post('http://localhost:8080/requests',body,options).subscribe(res=> console.log(res.headers));

    }
}
```

or return the observable and subscribe at caller site:

```
@Injectable()
export class requestService{

    constructor(private _http:Http){}

    postRequest(request:any){
        console.log("Here is post")
        const body=JSON.stringify(request);
        let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
        let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

        return this._http.post('http://localhost:8080/requests',body,options).map(res=> console.log(res.headers));

    }
}
```

```
this.requestService.postRequest.subscribe(val => console.log(val));
```