# Angular2 POST not sending data to server

Tags: ajax, servlets, angular

I have got a service which sends some http requests (all post) to a java servlet. At the servlet I print out the `method` variable from the code below. I had two request methods which work just fine but I made a third and the server is not receiving anything (probably).

**Service**

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {Employee} from './employee';

import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Rx';
import {Http, Response, Headers, RequestOptions} from '@angular/http';

@Injectable()
export class ManagementService{

private url = 'http://localhost:8080/whatever';

constructor(private http: Http) { }

getDepartments(): Observable<string[]> {

    let method = "getDepartments";
    let body = JSON.stringify({method});
    console.log(body);
    let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
    return this.http.post(this.url, body, options)
                    .map((res:Response) =>{ 
                            console.log(res.json());
                            return res.json();
                    }).catch(this.handleError);
}

getEmployees(department: string): Observable<Employee[]> {

        let method = "getEmployees";
        let body = JSON.stringify({method,department});
        console.log(body);
        let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
        let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
        return this.http.post(this.url, body, options)
                        .map((res:Response) =>{ 
                                console.log(res.json());
                                return res.json();
                        }).catch(this.handleError);
}

deleteEmployee(employee: Employee): any{

        let method = "deleteEmployee";
        let body = JSON.stringify({method,employee});
        console.log(body);
        let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
        let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
        return this.http.post(this.url, body, options)
                        .map((res:Response) =>{ 
                                console.log(res.json());
                                return res.json();
                        }).catch(this.handleError);
}


private handleError (error: any) {
     let errMsg = (error.message) ? error.message : error.status ? `${error.status} - ${error.statusText}` : 'Server error';
     console.error(errMsg);
     return Observable.throw(errMsg);
}

}
```

Comment: Looks like a dup of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39815722/http-post-request-does-not-work/39815757#39815757

Comment: Oh you are right. Sorry for that.

Comment: Is using observables even correct here? It is just a delete request which should return a success or failure message later on.

Comment: No I didn't and that was my mistake. Sorry I should have written this first.

Comment: Not sure what you mean with "correct". `http.xxx()` returns an observable, therefore you have to use observables.

Comment: I mean I have to subscribe to an observable which is empty but the server just deletes something. Seems a bit unlogical to me.

Comment: An observable is not only about the value, it's also about the completion of the request (with or without response value) or to communicate an error. They could also return a `Promise` you can chain code after completion with `.then()` but having observables allows to cancel requests (which `Promise` doesn't) and other request types might eventually support multiple result events and then still all requests have the same return type.

Comment: Ok then I will stay with Observables. As always thank you for your fast answers and help.